# not able to read browser cookie using HttpClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-security

I need to check browser cookie (along with id - password) to decide if user is valid or not.  I have set cookie in browser when user activates account. At the time of login I need to check for cookie along with credentials. I am using spring security (daoAuthenticationProvider) for authentication.
I am setting cookie using code :

```
public void setCookie(String token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, token);
        cookie.setDomain(cookieDomain);
        cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
        cookie.setMaxAge(31536000); // seconds for 365 days
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception in setting cookie : {}", e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

When it's a time to read cookie, I don't have `HttpServletRequest` object with me. Because it's not a spring controller where I can have request object. So I wrote a method in spring controller which will return the cookie value. Code is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "gettoken", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"text/html"})
public ResponseEntity<String> getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String token = "";
    Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

    if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Cookie details : " + cookies[i].getName()
            + "\t" + cookies[i].getValue());
            if (cookieName.equalsIgnoreCase(cookies[i].getName())) {
                token = cookies[i].getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("No cookies found...");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(token,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This spring controller action returns the cookie value. When I hit this URL, I can see returned cookie value in browser.

Now I call this URL from within the application using HttpClient. Code is :

```
public boolean isCookieValid(String token) {
    boolean valid = false;
    try {       
        String requestUrl = serverUrl + "gettoken";
        log.info("requestUrl is : {} ", requestUrl);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(requestUrl.trim());
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "text/html");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest,localContext);

        System.out.println("call success : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            return false;
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            String cookieToken = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println("Cookie Token : " + cookieToken);
            if(token.equalsIgnoreCase(cookieToken)) {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception in reading cookies : {}", e.getMessage());      
    }
    return valid;
}
```

When I hit spring action using http client, I receive HTTP 200 response code. But Spring controller is not able to read cookie. Any idea what could be the problem? Anybody  has better approach than this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getToken()` extracts the cookie from the request it receives. So, how do you expect a token back from it, when you send a request to it with `HttpClient` without adding any cookies to the request? When you use the browser to call `getToken()`, the browser sends any cookies set earlier by that same webapp along with the request. That's why you get the token back.

Comment: OK got it. What should I do to get the cookie set by webapp. Because I don't have http request object in the class where I need cookie value.

Comment: What's your original intention with that cookie? Do you really need it in addition to the user's credentials for authentication? That would prevent users from logging in with any browser other than the one they used originally to activate their account.

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I do not want user to log into system with browser other than the one from where account was activated.

Comment: Quite weird, but anyway in that case you'll have to implement your own  authentication filter, token, and provider. The filter should create a token that stores that cookie in addition to the user name and password, then the provider can check whether the cookie is valid. You  don't have to start from scratch, just subclass the classes already in use: `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, and `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.